# iphone cannot rotate views in TabBar controller

Tags: iphone, listview, rotation, autorotate

I am working on an application that consists of a TabBar controller.
Within on of its tab, I have a subclass of UITableViewController, within this list I have a Core-plot graph in the first cell and some other data in the 4 following cells.
When I return YES in the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method, I would expect the autoresizing of the list view to happen, but... nothing.
When I add some log in the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation method, they are not displayed.
Is there something I missed ?
Thanks a lot,
Luc

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
//return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
NSLog(@"Orientation");
return YES;
}
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
[super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation  duration:duration];

NSLog(@"Rotating");

if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    NSLog(@"view land:%@", self.view);
}

if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
{
    NSLog(@"view portrait:%@", self.view);
} 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it won't work unless you subclass `UITabBarController` and override its `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method correctly.

See [my question here and related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756536/tabbarcontroller-and-navigationcontrollers-in-landscape-mode-episode-ii).

Answer (score 0):

```
add this method in category 
@implementation UITabBarController(UITabBarControllerCategory)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
  AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

  if ([AppDelegate isLandScapeOnly]){
    return NO;
 }
return YES;
}
```