# Switch to Landscape Orientation

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an X-Code project where it is Portrait and it does not move from that. It is always on Portrait. How can I make it so that 1 page, by default, it is landscape?

If you can go into as much detail as possible, that would be great. I am newer to X-Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscapeRight(toInterfaceOrientation);
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

Comment: where do i implement this into my app? the class files that I used for the page i want to make landscape?

Comment: @CameronTarbell correct, the root view controller that you want landscape. If it is a further view down in the hierarchy you may need to send a notification message to the parent and have it change the view at the parent level.

Answer (score 1):

Follow those two steps on screenshot and you would be able to choose any orientation you want!

[image]

Or if you want it for specific view follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888016/ios-device-orientation-on-load).

Comment: yeah I know that part but i'm saying that I want to make it so that 1 view controller is landscape and not the entire project.

Comment: He wants it for a single view. Your specific view also only checks if the device is already rotated and not forcing it to a landscape view if it is in portrait mode.