# how to allow autorotation for child vc of vc in tabbar?

Tags: ios, autorotate

I have a tab bar view controller, which contains some navigation controllers each with a root view controller. Everything should only render in portrait. All's well. One of the child view controllers pushes another view controller using it's navigation vc, and that one I'd like to allow rotation to landscape on.

```
Tabbar vc
   nav vc/vc1
   nav vc/vc2
   nav vc/vc3
      pushes new vc4   <- ONLY this one should autorotate. Further more, if you're in landscape mode in this vc and hit 'back', it goes back in portrait.
```

The app 'line' does this - the actual 'chat' window can autorotate.

Please give me the codes! ;) I'm hoping it doesn't require messing with the transforms...

Answer (score 1):

To support autorotation on your UITabBarController application, you need to subclass the view controller rotation call on your tabBarController and ask the currently presented view controller if he supports the new orientation. In your specific case, vc4 will be asked if he supports the orientation change, so the tab bar can rotate when asked.

Take at look at this question: [tabBarController and navigationControllers in landscape mode, episode II](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756536/tabbarcontroller-and-navigationcontrollers-in-landscape-mode-episode-ii)

Comment: Almost! This does allow vc4 to rotate to landscape as I want. However, then when I pop vc4, vc3 remains in landscape - anyway I can force it to portrait?

Comment: try calling [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation]

Answer (score 0):

@Colin In ur Tabbar viewcontroller,restrict it to potrait like

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

and in ur new viewcontroller(vc4),restrict it to landscape.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) );
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Just wanna ask how r u adding ur tabbarcontroller in appdelegate? bcoz it works fine if u use [self.window addSubview:tabbarcontroller.view];